# How to calculate this limit with $x \to \infty$?

Tags: limits

$K$ is a Positive integer.

Now, I know this: given $z_k^s$ and $z_k^t$ real numbers such that $z_k^s<z_k^t$, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
 \lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \tau\left(\boldsymbol{p}_k^s(\tau)-\boldsymbol{p}_k^t(\tau)\right)&= \lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \tau\left(\frac{e^{\boldsymbol{z}_k^s / \tau}}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\boldsymbol{z}_j^s / \tau}}-\frac{e^{\boldsymbol{z}_k^t / \tau}}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\boldsymbol{z}_j^t / \tau}}\right) \\
&=\lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \tau\left(\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^s-\boldsymbol{z}_k^s\right) / \tau}}-\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^t-\boldsymbol{z}_k^t\right) / \tau}}\right) \\
&=\lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \tau\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^t-\boldsymbol{z}_k^t\right) / \tau}-\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^s-\boldsymbol{z}_k^s\right) / \tau}}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^s-\boldsymbol{z}_k^s\right) / \tau}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^t-\boldsymbol{z}_k^t\right) / \tau}\right)}\right) \\
&= \lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^K \tau\left(e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^t-\boldsymbol{z}_k^t\right) / \tau}-1\right)-\sum_{j=1}^K \tau\left(e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^s-\boldsymbol{z}_k^s\right) / \tau}-1\right)}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^s-\boldsymbol{z}_k^s\right) / \tau}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^K e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^t-\boldsymbol{z}_k^t\right) / \tau}\right)}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{K^2} \sum_{j=1}^K\left(\left(\boldsymbol{z}_k^s-\boldsymbol{z}_j^s\right)-\left(\boldsymbol{z}_k^t-\boldsymbol{z}_j^t\right)\right)=\frac{1}{K}\left(\boldsymbol{z}_k^s-\boldsymbol{z}_k^t\right)-\frac{1}{K^2} \sum_{j=1}^K\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^s-\boldsymbol{z}_j^t\right) \\
& \quad\left(\because \lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty} e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^f-\boldsymbol{z}_k^f\right) / \tau}=1, \lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \tau\left(e^{\left(\boldsymbol{z}_j^f-\boldsymbol{z}_k^f\right) / \tau}-1\right)=\boldsymbol{z}_j^f-\boldsymbol{z}_k^f\right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$ thus
$$
\lim _{\tau \rightarrow 0} \tau\left(\boldsymbol{p}_k^s(\tau)-\boldsymbol{p}_k^t(\tau)\right)=0\quad\left(\because-1 \leq \boldsymbol{p}_k^s(\tau)-\boldsymbol{p}_k^t(\tau) \leq 1\right)
$$
But how to calculate the following related limit?

$$
\lim _{\tau \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\tau^2}{\ln \tau}\left(\frac{e^{z_k^s / \ln \tau}}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{z_j^s / \ln \tau}}-\frac{e^{z_k^t / \tau}}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{z_j^t / \tau}}\right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

The first result you have added has correctness. For the second, Applying limit in expressions inside the bracket ($(A=p_k^s(\ln \tau)$) - (B $=$ p$_k^t(\tau$)) using the fact that $\ln\tau \to \infty$ as $ \tau \to \infty$. You can convince yourself that $A=B=1/K$ and hence the limit is zero. The evaluation of the whole expression is independent of the limit of expression outside the bracket which is infinity (Only for this particular case), The same applies for the limit expression at the start.